# Android Studio code format linebreak after "("

Tags: android, android-studio

When I format the code, Android Studio breaks the line like this (before "(")):

```
if ((message.getSeverity() == WsMessage.WsMessageSeverity.ERROR) && !TextUtils.isEmpty
                        (renderedMessage)) {
```

But I want it like this:

```
if ((message.getSeverity() == WsMessage.WsMessageSeverity.ERROR) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(
                         renderedMessage)) {
```

Can i change the settings to achieve this?

Comment: why do you want this but  -_-

Comment: because sonarcube marks this as a major error - '(' should be on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Android Studio has an option for that because I have never seen anyone recommend formatting code like that.

Android Studio uses that format as default *for a reason* - most people like it this way.

"But if I break at (, it would be clear that there must be a continuation of the method call. Code Complete even mentioned it!" you shouted.

Well, yes, it is *clearer*, but the method has only got one parameter! IMO, breaking the line there just looks weird. I mean if the method has more arguments, it looks kind of OK:

```
method(
    arg1, arg2,
    arg3, arg4
)
```

To let people know that there is a continuation, you can break the line at `&&`.

```
if ((message.getSeverity() == WsMessage.WsMessageSeverity.ERROR) &&
    !TextUtils.isEmpty(renderedMessage)) {
```